# Dynamic requests with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to use JMeter to do load testsing.
I will use the requests to simulate user behavior on my website.
Depending on what a user is filling out on the page, new fields may appear and these must be filled out.
For example if a user chooses a value in a dropdown box, depending on this value can appear below the text fields and / or the radio button group, etc. it is quite unpredictable so the possibilities are wide.
That's why I made a little program with Selenium to build a dataset based on what the application presents to me as fields.
So I can not present a CSV with a quantity of fixed columns since this one is dynamic according to the different choices of the users.
How would you have implemented this?